# Extremely long linking time on windows but not Linux

Tags: c++, windows, build, compilation, linker

I have a program that on Linux compiles and links in about 15 minutes from scratch, and then takes about 1 minute to compile on subsequent rebuilds.

The exact same program is taking hours to link on windows. The compilation step is the same, but it just gets hanged on the linking step for a really long time.

Is there a way to profile what is bottlenecking compilation?

I am trying to compile on Win10 using meson as the build system and VS through the command line as the compiler and cl as the linker.

Comment: Windows Defender scan seriously impact build times.  Turn off Windows Defender scanning for your code, compile, and linking folders by specifying folders to exclude: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26

Comment: Is there chance that Linux build uses shared libraries whereas Windows uses static linking?

Comment: There is a chance, but would that cause a discrepancy of minutes vs hours?

Comment: Also, any other anti-virus program in addition to Defender is going to do their own "scan on write" logic. So my original advice is more generalized: Turn off ALL anti-virus software or set each to exclude your build folders from virus scanning.

Comment: I don;t have any other anti virus and I both disabled all anti virus protection in windows AND added the folder to the exception list :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to profile but you can normally significantly speed up link via [/incremental](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=msvc-170) and [/debug:fastlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=msvc-170) flags.